# Como exibir os dados do ultimo registro salvo no banco

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

como faço para exibir na view somente os dados do último registro salvo no banco? consigo exibir todos os dados chamando o método All() no controle, e o bom e velho foreach na view para exibir os dados. Porém, queria que quando o usuário finaliza-se o cadastro ele fosse redirecionado para uma página, onde ele pudesse conferir os dados que cadastrou.

obs:estou usando laravel, eloquent orm, mysql

no controle tenho essa action para pegar todos os dados

```html
public function exibe(){
  $dados = Denuncia::all();
  return view('AdminDenunciaView.exibeInformacao',['dados'=>$dados]);
}
```

na view uso este foreach para exibir os dados

```html
@foreach ($dados as $item)
   {{$item->crime}}.<br/>
   {{$item->infrator}}.<br/>
@endforeach
```

Mas como mencionei, não preciso que todos os dados sejam mostrados, apenas os dados ultimo registro

Comment: mysqli_insert_id - Retorna o id gerado automaticamente na última consulta. Com isso vc faz seu select com where nomeColuna = id gerado automaticamente na ultima consulta   https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode dar um order by pelo id mais alto (último adicionado) e pegar o primeiro registro da lista retornada, com o first() do eloquent.

exemplo: `DB::table('tabela')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();`

Dessa forma o primeiro da lista vai ser o ultimo id adicionado, e essa query vai te retornar **apenas 1 resultado**.

Comment: Olá Sara! valeu pelo feedback, seguindo o exemplo que você  postou  obtive a seguinte resposta. Você está tentando usar o método orderBy() na coleção Eloquent. Pequisei um pouco mais e descobrir que teria que usar o método sortByDesc, pois este já classifica a coleção na ordem oposta. Logo depois, uso método First para capturar o primeiro na ordem oposta, vlw muito obrigado.

ficou assim 
Denuncia::all()->sortByDesc('id')->first();

Comment: Oi, que bom que ajudei!! vlw pela resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Na query você poderia dar um order by, para listar o ultimo registro.

Exemplo: `select * from clientes order by cliente_id desc`

Assim retornaria o ultimo registro cadastrado.

Comment: valeu pelo feedback, mas dessa forma é retornado todos registros, porém na ordem decrescente. A idea é lista apenas o último registro

Comment: Você pode colocar o limit 1(MYSQL).

Answer (score 0):

para ordenar pelo último registro você pode fazer o select order by desc
Exemplo

```
select * from tabelaExemplo order by tabelaExemplo_id  desc
```

Para pegar somente o ultimo registro do banco você pode fazer assim:

```
select * from tabelaExemplo where tabelaExemplo.id = select max(id) from tabelaExemplo
```

Comment: obg por tentar ajudar, mas seguindo a 1ª resposta é retornado todos os registro, porém em forma decrescente, mas a ideia é retornar apenas o ultimo registro.  Já a 2ª resposta está mostrando um erro de sintaxe